# How to automatically overwrite the output file when running `gpg` (i.e. without being prompted)?

Tags: gnupg

If I have the same filename in the target directory, decryption fails.

The command I'm using to decrypt:

```
gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -o D:/Notification/mytest.txt --batch \
  --passphrase-file D:/passphrase.txt -d D:/Notification/mytest.gpg
```

It doesn't overwrite the *mytest.txt* file so each time I need to delete the file before I execute the script.

Is there any option to overwrite the output fie?

Comment: This seems like a question for super-user

Comment: Answer: Don't use `-o`, just do `gpg ... > output.txt`

Comment: @wisbucky except if you need root permissions for the file, and you don't necessarily want to `tee` it...

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Adding `--batch --yes`

Example:

```
gpg --batch --yes -u me@bbb.com -r "you@aaa.com" \
  --output "OUTPUTFILENAME.xls.pgp" -a -s -e "FILE.xls"
```

Complete example with passphrase file:

```
gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 -u me@bbb.com -r "you@aaa.com" \
  --output "OUTPUTFILENAME.xls.pgp" -a -s -e "FILE.xls"< \
  passphrase.txt
```

Comment: please explain why both flags are needed

Comment: In my experience, just `gpg --yes --dearmor ...` worked fine

Answer (score 45):

Just add the `--yes` option to you command line. The `--yes` option assumes yes for most questions which `gpg` will prompt for.

Source: http://www.gnupg.org/gph/de/manual/r1023.html

Comment: Isn't that dangerous, in that it will answer "yes" to questions other than "file exists - overwrite?"

Comment: Agreed! gpg asks you if you have not signed the recipients keys, and you will be saying "yes", right?

Comment: `rm -f filename.gpg && gpg2 [...] -o filename.gpg filename` may be appropriate in most cases.